# I am able to capture the TAB in a jtable, but how do I capture the SHIFT+TAB?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, key-events

I have a `JTable` that I need to change the traversal inside such that a TAB keystroke advances row by row.  (Normally, the TAB keystroke advances cell by cell.)  I was able to change the forward traversal on the TAB keystroke.  I tried the same thing for reverse traversal on SHIFT+TAB.  I can't capture the SHIFT+TAB.

```
    InputMap im = myTable.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    ActionMap am = myTable.getActionMap();

    // make shift+tab row to row instead of cell to cell
    Action shiftTabActionmyTable = new AbstractAction("SHIFT+TAB")
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!inside");
            int rowView = myTable.getSelectedRow();
            int numRows = myTable.getRowCount();

            if (0 < numRows)
            {
                if ((-1 == rowView) || (0 == rowView))
                {
                    // Move to last row
                    rowView = numRows - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Move to prev row
                    rowView--;
                 }

                myTable.changeSelection(rowView, 0, false, false);
                myTable.scrollRectToVisible(myTable.getCellRect(rowView, COL_ICON, true));
            }
        }
    };
    KeyStroke VK_Shift_Tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SHIFT+TAB");
    im.put(VK_Shift_Tab, shiftTabActionmyTable.getValue(Action.NAME));
    am.put(shiftTabActionmyTable.getValue(Action.NAME), shiftTabActionmyTable);

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Name " + shiftTabActionmyTable.getValue(Action.NAME));


    // Make tab row to row instead of cell to cell
    Action tabActionmyTable = new AbstractAction("TAB")
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int rowView = myTable.getSelectedRow();
            int numRows = myTable.getRowCount();

            if (0 < numRows)
            {
                if ((-1 == rowView) || ((numRows - 1) == rowView))
                {
                    // Move to first row
                    rowView = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Move to next row
                    rowView++;
                }

                myTable.changeSelection(rowView, 0, false, false);
                myTable.scrollRectToVisible(myTable.getCellRect(rowView, COL_ICON, true));
            }
         }
    };
    KeyStroke VK_Tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB");
    im.put(VK_Tab, tabActionmyTable.getValue(Action.NAME));
    am.put(tabActionmyTable.getValue(Action.NAME), tabActionmyTable);
```

How do I capture SHIFT+TAB in a `JTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
KeyStroke VK_Shift_Tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB,
            InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
```

or use

```
KeyStroke VK_Shift_Tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift TAB");
```

instead of

```
KeyStroke VK_Shift_Tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SHIFT+TAB");
```

And it should work.

The documentation of [`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke-java.lang.String-) states

> Parses a string and returns a KeyStroke. The string must have the
>   following syntax:
>
> ```
> <modifiers>* (<typedID> | <pressedReleasedID>)
>
> modifiers := shift | control | ctrl | meta | alt | altGraph
> typedID := typed <typedKey>
> typedKey := string of length 1 giving Unicode character.
> pressedReleasedID := (pressed | released) key
> key := KeyEvent key code name, i.e. the name following "VK_".
> ```
>
> If typed, pressed or released is not specified, pressed is assumed.
>   Here are some examples:
>
> ```
>  "INSERT" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_INSERT, 0);
>  "control DELETE" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
>  "alt shift X" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK);
>  "alt shift released X" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK, true);
>  "typed a" => getKeyStroke('a');
> ```